# MVC Model, how to put Error Message in model without using Requried or Compare attribute?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

My question may looks weird but I really want to ask how I can set a error message which will be displayed by some custom conditional validation in Action ?

I cant decorate field with `[Required] or [Compare]` because I will do some conditional validation in action and will add error message to `ModelState`

I tried the following code but in View it shows two error messages one I added in Action and second appear by default may be which I have not declared anywhere. Can you please guide how I can edit this default error message.

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ApplicantDetails.PartnerDOB.ToString()))
{
  ModelState.AddModelError("ApplicantDetails.PartnerDOB", "Partner DOB is required");
}
```

In view I only have:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary();
```

Not showing error messages with fields.

In View it shows two messages:

> Partner DOB is required
>
> The field PartnerGender must be a string or array type with a maximum length of '1'.

EDIT:

```
 public partial class App_Step2
{
    public int LeadSequence { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string GivenName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DOB { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string Suburb { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsPostal { get; set; }
    public string PostalAddress1 { get; set; }
    public string PostalAddress2 { get; set; }
    public string Postalsuburb { get; set; }
    public string PostalState { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string WorkPhone { get; set; }
    public string HomePhone { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> ContinuousCover { get; set; }
    public string PartnerTitle { get; set; }
    public string PartnerName { get; set; }
    public string PartnerSurname { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> PartnerDOB { get; set; }
    public string PartnerGender { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> PartnerContinuousCover { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Conditions { get; set; }
    public string ConditionsText { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Insertedon { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Modifiedon { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I can't see your "following" code.

Comment: Please add the View and Controller code. Also the code you tried.

Comment: Did you remove attribute from ApplicantDetails.PartnerDOB property? Looks like UI is picking up the attribute and then ModelError.

Comment: What is typeof `PartnerDOB` and `PartnerGender` ? Include your model with these properties

Comment: There's still something you're not showing. The validation message for `PartnerGender` has to be coming from somewhere.

Comment: The second one appears to be a `DbEntityValidationException` probably generated by CodeFirst. Have your made some changes to the model but not updated the database?

Comment: @Shoe I have not declared it anywhere. Any idea pleas where I should check for this ?

Comment: @StephenMuecke,I can confirm it do not go to DB. Just in action it is returning the message.